# Is the image size and bitmap size equivalent in android?

Tags: android, bitmap, size, byte

I am little bit confusing because i am calculate the size of of an image.

I am using the following code in android:-

```
String fileUrl = getIntent().getExtras().getString("fileurl");
BitmapFactory.Options option = new BitmapFactory.Options();
option.inPurgeable = true;

Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileUrl,option);
        Log.e("Fill Image Size in Bytes","====>"+bitmap.getByteCount());
```

The above function bitmap.getByteCount() return different value compare to original size of image(compare with right click of image size in ubuntu).

If anyone have idea.please reply.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: what is the value of actual size of your Image in bytes and value that returned from getByteCount()?

Answer (score 0):

You can decode the bitmap without options to see what's the difference.

```
Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileUrl);
Log.e("Fill Image Size in Bytes","====>"+bitmap.getByteCount());
```

the default value of options may scale down the size.

Answer (score 0):

It may be decided by Bitmap.config and bitmap size.